# Python heapq vs sorted speed for pre-sorted lists

Tags: python, list, sorting, merge

I have a reasonably large number n=10000 of sorted lists of length k=100 each. Since merging two sorted lists takes linear time, I would imagine its cheaper to recursively merge the sorted lists of length O(nk) with `heapq.merge()` in a tree of depth log(n) than to sort the entire thing at once with `sorted()` in O(nklog(nk)) time.

However, the `sorted()` approach seems to be 17-44x faster on my machine. Is the implementation of `sorted()` that much faster than `heapq.merge()` that it outstrips the asymptotic time advantage of the classic merge?

```
import itertools
import heapq

data = [range(n*8000,n*8000+10000,100) for n in range(10000)]

# Approach 1
for val in heapq.merge(*data):
    test = val

# Approach 2
for val in sorted(itertools.chain(*data)):
    test = val
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

CPython's `list.sort()` uses an adaptive merge sort, which identifies natural runs in the input, and then merges them "intelligently".  It's very effective at exploiting many kinds of pre-existing order.  For example, try sorting `range(N)*2` (in Python 2) for increasing values of `N`, and you'll find the time needed grows linearly in `N`.

So the only real advantage of `heapq.merge()` in this application is lower peak memory use *if* you iterate over the results (instead of materializing an ordered list containing all the results).

In fact, `list.sort()` is taking *more* advantage of the structure in your specific data than the `heapq.merge()` approach.  I have some insight into this, because I wrote Python's `list.sort()` ;-)

(BTW, I see you already accepted an answer, and that's fine by me - it's a good answer.  I just wanted to give a bit more info.)

### ABOUT THAT "more advantage"

As discussed a bit in comments, `list.sort()` plays lots of engineering tricks that *may* cut the number of comparisons needed over what `heapq.merge()` needs.  It depends on the data.  Here's a quick account of what happens for the specific data in your question.  First define a class that counts the number of comparisons performed (note that I'm using Python 3, so have to account for all possible comparisons):

```
class V(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def __lt__(a, b):
        global ncmp
        ncmp += 1
        return a.val < b.val

    def __eq__(a, b):
        global ncmp
        ncmp += 1
        return a.val == b.val

    def __le__(a, b):
        raise ValueError("unexpected comparison")

    __ne__ = __gt__ = __ge__ = __le__
```

`sort()` was deliberately written to use only `<` (`__lt__`).  It's more of an accident in `heapq` (and, as I recall, even varies across Python versions), but it turns out `.merge()` only required `<` and `==`.  So those are the only comparisons the class defines in a useful way.

Then changing your data to use instances of that class:

```
data = [[V(i) for i in range(n*8000,n*8000+10000,100)]
        for n in range(10000)]
```

Then run both methods:

```
ncmp = 0
for val in heapq.merge(*data):
    test = val
print(format(ncmp, ","))

ncmp = 0
for val in sorted(itertools.chain(*data)):
    test = val
print(format(ncmp, ","))
```

The output is kinda remarkable:

```
43,207,638
1,639,884
```

So `sorted()` required *far* fewer comparisons than `merge()`, for this specific data.  And that's the primary reason it's much faster.

### LONG STORY SHORT

Those comparison counts looked *too* remarkable to me ;-)  The count for `heapq.merge()` looked about twice as large as I thought reasonable.

Took a while to track this down.  In short, it's an artifact of the way `heapq.merge()` is implemented:  it maintains a heap of 3-element list objects, each containing the current next value from an iterable, the 0-based index of that iterable among all the iterables (to break comparison ties), and that iterable's `__next__` method.  The `heapq` functions all compare these little lists (instead of *just* the iterables' values), and list comparison always goes thru the lists first looking for the first corresponding items that are not `==`.

So, e.g., asking whether `[0] < [1]` *first* asks whether `0 == 1`.  It's not, so *then* it goes on to ask whether `0 < 1`.

Because of this, each `<` comparison done during the execution of `heapq.merge()` actually does two object comparisons (one `==`, the other `<`).  The `==` comparisons are "wasted" work, in the sense that they're not logically necessary to solve the problem - they're just "an optimization" (which happens not to pay in this context!) used internally by list comparison.

So in some sense it would be fairer to cut the report of `heapq.merge()` comparisons in half.  But it's still way more than `sorted()` needed, so I'll let it drop now ;-)

Comment: Thanks, the additional insight about the pattern exploitation and memory use is actually very helpful for my application. I switched my answer selection, I'm @user2357112 doesn't mind, he already has plenty of rep :)

Comment: Oh, hi Tim! How is `sorted` taking advantage of preexisting order better than `heapq.merge`? The lists don't quite chain together into one big sorted run, so `sorted` doesn't get to just go "hey, we're done!" Are you talking about the binary searches to cut down the merged area when merging adjacent runs?

Comment: That's partly what I had in mind, although it really depends on the exact values in the lists. `heapq.merge()` has to do `O(log(n))` comparisons for every output; regardless of the exact values.  Depending on exact values, `sort()` _can_ get off cheaper both due to pre-merge binary-ish search and due to in-merge "galloping mode".  I didn't analyze that for the `range(n*8000,n*8000+10000,100)` given in the question, because if that was their _actual_ data the OP wouldn't have to run a program to get the result ;-) More precise to say `sort()` _may_ get off cheaper.

Answer (score 3):

`sorted` uses an [adaptive mergesort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) that detects sorted runs and merges them efficiently, so it gets to take advantage of all the same structure in the input that `heapq.merge` gets to use. Also, `sorted` has a really nice C implementation with a lot more optimization effort put into it than `heapq.merge`.